# Change Button Color dynamically with the Integer Value

Tags: android, colors, interpolation

I want to change the Button color with the Integer Value. So if my Integer Value is 1 it should be green once it goes up it should change dynamically to yellow and at the end should change to red. How can i implement this.

I tried with interpolation but i can't get the value i need its changing the color but not very precise.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know whether this is helpful.

```
yourButtonName.setBackgroundColor(colorIntVariable);
```

"colorIntVariable" is a self chosen variable name for an integer created with the rgb method:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb(int,%20int,%20int)

```
int colorIntVariable = rgb(0,255,0);
```

Above code can be used for displaying a green object.

An example can be:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button yourButtonName;
    Button plusButton;
    Button minusButton;
    int red;
    int green;
    int input = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        yourButtonName = findViewById(R.id.button);

        plusButton = findViewById(R.id.plusbutton);
        minusButton = findViewById(R.id.minusbutton);

        plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                input = input + 10;
                changeButtonColor(input);
            }
        });

        minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                input = input - 10;
                changeButtonColor(input);
            }
        });


    }

    public void changeButtonColor(int inputValue) {

        if(inputValue <= 256) {
            green = 255;
            red = inputValue -1;
        }
        else {
            green = 255 - (inputValue - 256);
            red = 255;
        }

        int colorIntVariable = rgb(red,green,0);

        yourButtonName.setBackgroundColor(colorIntVariable);

    }
}
```